# An efficient algorithm for calculating frequencies?

Tags: math, statistics, intervals

I have a data set of frequency samples (for example, bpm, or any other measure/time), taken at regular time intervals (say, every 5 minutes). I would like to find the smallest set of time intervals with the following properties:

- The intervals cover the entire original data-set
- No time interval has an average frequency below a given threshold

Are there any standard algorithms for figuring this sort of information out?

Comment: This looks to me like the type of problem that has no algorithmic solution, and that can only be tackled by brute force. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Brute force is, if it helps arrive at a solution, a sound basis for a perfectly acceptable algorithmic solution.

Comment: It could be worth it to try defining the terms "frequency sample" (is that a number or a vector?), "average frequency", "interval" (are the input intervals overlapping?), etc. It seems that some folks here have the domain knowledge and don't need these details, but you may get a broader set of responses if you make the question more approachable. E.g., I read the question a few times, but have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken:

- If the average of the whole thing is above your threshold, then the single interval covering the entire set is the solution
- If the average of the entire set is below your threshold, there is no solution.

Comment: You are mistaken :) You can drive at an average speed of 120 km/h for an hour, by doing 240km in 30 minutes and then stopping.

Comment: @blueberryfields: what would be the intervals then which work? [0,.5] would have an average of 240, but (.5,1] would have an average of 0, below any (positive) threshold.

Comment: Right! The requirement to cover the original data-set forces that.

Comment: @blueberryfields: I don't think I understand your question. Can you give an example in which a single interval doesn't meet the requirements, but a set of spanning intervals does?

Comment: Your answer is right for the question as I wrote it. The problem I'm looking at has more complexities, though, I'll have to think about it some more before I can frame the question properly.